# Qt 5: how to make a "pure c++" client socket?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtnetwork

I am building a QtQuick app, and i need a TCPSocket that polls a device and fills the data structures I want to show. I've found a lot of samples about sockets and Qt 5 widgets, but i'm not able to create the socket as a C++ class that's not derived from QObject.

My understanding is that I only need to derive from QObject if I want to exchange data with my QML view. I wrote an additional class that does that, so my socket class doesn't have a need to pass any data to my QML code.

Comment: Have you looked at QTcpSocket?

Comment: Yes. My starting point was the "FortuneCookie" sample, which uses the QTcpSocket.
I stripped down almost all code until i had a QObject which, once created, get the localhostname and the other basic proprierties from my machine.
I'm trying to avoid the QOBject derived class, but i don't know how to create "events" between my c++ code instead of signals and slots for QML.
Also, some methodes ceased to compile while the class is'nt a QObject anymore

Comment: Either you use Qt or you don't. Why bother with Qt if you don't want to use it? The idea that QObjects are somehow bad is usually wrong. They do exactly what you need them to do. You want to write asynchronous code that gives you good user experience. You need QObjects, QEvents and the event loop, and all it entails. Besides, you have a wrong idea of what a socket is. Sockets are dumb. What you call a socket is called by everyone else in the world a network client. If you don't want to use moc-generated code, it's usually because you have no handle on your build system. Learn it, use it.

Comment: 1st: I am so sorry that my english is not fluent enough. I do my best. 2nd: "Learn it": that's exactly what i'm trying to do. So this is the question i pose to you now: are'nt QObject derived classes made to be used in the QML files? Or am i wrong and i have misunderstood them, and i should use QObject derived classes even if the UI don't have to use them?
My goal is to have a UI that is unaware about who is feeding the data (a serial, a tcp client, or a simulation)... that is the reason i did'nt want to use a QObject... based on the assumption that they exists to be used in the QML UI. Thanks

Comment: QObject is not a GUI-specific class, it is useful whenever you want an object that can use signals and slots.  QObject dates back to the original version of Qt, it is much older than QML and is in no way QML-specific.

Comment: I think the underlying confusion makes for a valuable question so I edited it and I hope others agree and the Jeremy will promote his comment to an answer.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: signals and slots are actually not the only features for QObject, so your reasoning is partial. Also, note that for proper QML'ing, you do need QObjects at the current moment. That may confuse the OP.

Comment: @KubaOber: Actually, you can use certain Qt classes without QObjects just fine. You do not need to add QObject for the inheritance just for the sake of QObject.

Comment: @FabioCalzolari: would it be possible to show the code what you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

The question almost doesn't seem to be a Qt question, but a C++ network programming question. I gather that you basically dislike explicitly using custom `QObject`-derived classes since you don't want to run `moc` as a part of your build process. While one might argue what's so bad about it, since `moc` is run *a whole lot* during the building of Qt proper, let's go with what's asked for the moment.

If you're looking for non-Qt-based pure-C++ networking, then [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/) is a very solid solution.

If you wish to use Qt networking without a custom `QObject`-derived class, then you can run the code in a separate thread and only use blocking `QTCPSocket` calls. After all, it's a `QIODevice` and offers blocking interface.

Eventually, you end up with some data structure that's filled and should be passed on to QML.

Logically your data is a data model, and the view is in the QML code. You can use `QStandardItemModel` for that - that is, if you are writing true model-view code, like you would if the data will change over time. Again, you're re-using an existing `QObject`-derived class, without deriving your own, without writing any custom signals nor slots.

A really poor-man's workaround is to take a naked `QObject` and put data in it using the dynamic property system via `QObject::setProperty`. I don't recall offhand if dynamic property changes are seen via the QML engine, you'd need to verify that or simply treat such objects as constants.

All of this seems to be a lot of workarounds for a rather silly reservation. Code generators are good, they save time. The build process of a complex C++-based product may use several different code generators, such as lexer/parser generators, state machine generators, remote procedure call generators, table generators, test case generators, etc. As C++ matures, ways are found to coax the compiler to replace some of those generators, but that's merely pushing the problem to a different executable, and sometimes pushing it through a very small needle hole as well.